# Prevent float element from dropping down on window scaling

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer

How do I avoid a floating element from dropping down when the window has been scaled as in below screenshot?

[image: web page screenshot]

I tried setting min-width on the container but IE7 and FF interpret it differently and columns appear of different widths yielding:

[image]

The fiddle is here http://jsfiddle.net/GEgYm/

```
<body>

<div id="wrapper1">
<div id="header">
    <h1>This is the header</h1>
</div>
        <div id="maincol">
            <div id="leftcol">
                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Aenean tincidunt nunc ut ipsum vestibulum semper. In hac habitasse platea dictumst. Nam accumsan leo malesuada, molestie enim bibendum, suscipit sapien. Etiam tempus tempus sapien, nec hendrerit orci dapibus id. Aliquam fermentum purus id pellentesque imperdiet. Donec ac condimentum sapien, at pretium dolor. Donec imperdiet vitae nibh quis pulvinar. Morbi diam ligula, molestie mattis tincidunt non, tempus vitae dui. Mauris odio turpis, egestas lacinia imperdiet sed, dignissim eget nibh. </p>
            </div>

            <div id="rightcol">
                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Aenean tincidunt nunc ut ipsum vestibulum semper. In hac habitasse platea dictumst. Nam accumsan leo malesuada, molestie enim bibendum, suscipit sapien. Etiam tempus tempus sapien, nec hendrerit orci dapibus id. Aliquam fermentum purus id pellentesque imperdiet. Donec ac condimentum sapien, at pretium dolor. Donec imperdiet vitae nibh quis pulvinar. Morbi diam ligula, molestie mattis tincidunt non, tempus vitae dui. Mauris odio turpis, egestas lacinia imperdiet sed, dignissim eget nibh. </p>
            </div>

            <div id="centercol">
                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Aenean tincidunt nunc ut ipsum vestibulum semper. In hac habitasse platea dictumst. Nam accumsan leo malesuada, molestie enim bibendum, suscipit sapien. Etiam tempus tempus sapien, nec hendrerit orci dapibus id. Aliquam fermentum purus id pellentesque imperdiet. Donec ac condimentum sapien, at pretium dolor. Donec imperdiet vitae nibh quis pulvinar. Morbi diam ligula, molestie mattis tincidunt non, tempus vitae dui. Mauris odio turpis, egestas lacinia imperdiet sed, dignissim eget nibh. </p>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div id="footer">
            <p>This is the footer</p>
        </div>
</div>

</body>
```

css:

```
body {
    text-align:center;
    margin:20px;
    padding:0;
    font:normal 0.8em/1.2em verdana,aria,sans-serif;
    color:#666;
    }
#wrapper1 {
    position:relative;
    text-align:left;
    width:80%;
    margin:auto;
    }
#header {
    background:#BB62AB;
    padding:10px;
    margin:0;
    text-align:center;
    color:#FFF;
    }
#maincol {
    position:relative;
    margin:0;
    padding:10px;
    }
#leftcol { 
    position:relative;
    top:-10px;
    left:-10px;
    float:left;
    width:220px;  /* for IE5/WIN */
    width:22%; /* actual value */
    margin:0 0 -10px 0;
    padding:10px;
    background:#ECB9E8;
    z-index:100;
    }
#rightcol {
    position:relative;
    top:-10px;
    right:-10px;
    float:right;
    width:220px;  /* for IE5/WIN */
    width:22%; /* actual value */
    margin:0 0 -10px 0;
    padding:10px;
    background:#D7C4FA;
    z-index:99;
    }
#centercol {
    float: left;
    position:relative;
    padding:0 2px;
    width:50%;
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This happens because of the `padding` you use in all 3 floating containers. Try to remove the padding or even better use the `padding` in the children containers.

**[See the demo](http://jsfiddle.net/GEgYm/1/)**.

I have included padding in the `p` tag instead of the parent container. Now all 3 columns don't collapse.

An alternative approach is to use percentage widths (or absolute values if you know the width of the parent) to the columns AND include the `padding` values so that the sum of the widths would be equal to (or less than) 100%. Example:

```
    #rightcol{width:23%; padding:0 1%} /*25%*/
    #leftcol{width:23%; padding:0 1%} /*25%*/
    #midcol{width:48%; padding:0 1%} /*50%*/
```

Note: If you use `border` you should also include the widths of borders in the overall width of the parent. Even if you're using 1px border, it will make the floating element to collapse.

Comment: how can I use the above in combination with a min-width so that columns don't get narrower than say 100px? I tried setting min-width: 400px; in maincol and wrapper1 to no effect.

Comment: @dendini just add the `min-width` in combination with `width:100%` in the parent container. In your case: `#wrapper1{width:100%;min-width:400px;}`. Here's the demo: http://jsfiddle.net/GEgYm/4/

Comment: Also, don't forget to choose an answer if you're happy with any of the given ones.

Answer (score 0):

It is still fine to use padding, however you should add padding into the calculation with the width sizes.

So `padding + col1 + padding + col2 + padding + col3 + padding = 100%`

Using a fixed pixel size for padding, causes the total calculation to become greater than 100% when reducing the size of the window.

for example `100px padding + 80% width + 100px padding` would become more than 100% if the window were smaller than 1000px.

Answer (score 0):

Modify #centercol id to this one (tested in firefox and IE10 with IE9 mode):

`#centercol { margin: 0 auto; max-width: 50%;  padding: 0 2px;  position: relative;}`

jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/xzjHv/